# How to tell apache to look for last modified date before serving an old modified HTML file?

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, django, mod-cache, last-modified

On certain requests my Django application updates static HTML files.

However apache is serving them old copy from its cache...

How can I configure Apache to make sure serve latest file changes..

This changes are not so frequent but as changes are done by portal users we can't predict how frequent and how long it would happen.

If we can configure apache to check the last modified date before serving cached copy may do.

Comment: What's your current configuration?  Since you tagged this question as such, are you using `mod_cache`?  Can you clarify what you need it for?

Comment: I found a solution for apache configuration to use "FileETag" with MTime option

Comment: Right, `FileETag INode MTime Size` is the default so that should have been already enabled, but that manipulates the client's browser cache, not any cache on the server side.